# InvalidArgumentError: for tensor bool tensorflow==0.12.1

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have experimented with `tensorflow==0.12.1` and I have following problem:

I am trying to run:

```
inp = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10, 10, 3], name='inp')
var = tf.nn.batch_normalization(inp, mean, variance, offset, scale, variance_epsilon)
training = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, name='training')
x1 = np.random.random([20, 10, 10, 3])

config = tf.ConfigProto(device_count={'GPU': 0})
with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    result = var.eval({inp: x1, training: True}, sess)
```

But I'm getting following stack trace:

> File "myscript.py", line 35, in tf_run
>       sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 766, in run
>       run_metadata_ptr)
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 964, in _run
>       feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1014, in _do_run
>       target_list, options, run_metadata)
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1034, in _do_call
>       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
>       InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'training' with dtype bool      [[Node: training =
>   Placeholderdtype=DT_BOOL, shape=[],
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]
>
> ```
> Caused by op u'training', defined at:
>     File "myscript.py", line 30, in tf_run
> training = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, name='training')
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py",
> ```
>
> line 1587, in placeholder
>       name=name)
>           File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py",
>   line 2043, in _placeholder
>       name=name)
>           File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py",
>   line 759, in apply_op
>       op_def=op_def)
>          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 2240, in create_op
>       original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
>          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 1128, in **init**
>       self._traceback = _extract_stack()

This problem appears on:
`Ubuntu 16.04.1 - tensorflow GPU` installation
`Mac - tensorflow CPU` only installation

When I try to downgrade to `tensorflow==0.11.0` and replace line

`sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()`
 by 
`sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())`, then everything works well.

Related issue in tensorflow repo is here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6661

Comment: What is the definition of `var`?

Comment: Also, you define a placeholder `training` but you feed a value for the tensor `is_training`.

Comment: @fabian789 sorry it was just a typo, both were `training` and `var` is a tensorflow tensor.

Comment: Well the log says you are not passing a value for the placeholder 'is_training' so maybe there is some other placeholder you are missing?

Comment: I was doing some refactoring from `is_training` to `training`, the new correct log was updated. It's `training` placeholder. Still the code works with `tensorflow=0.11`, but not with `tensorflow==0.12.1`

Comment: I just saw that the error is actually about `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())` missing a value for the `training` placeholder. So it seems that you have to feed values for `training` there too, i.e., `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer(), {training: True})`. This makes me really curious as to how `var` is defined, do you mind sharing?

Comment: It's basically a tensor, that comes out of `var = tf.nn.batch_normalization(inp, mean, variance, offset, scale, variance_epsilon)` and `inp = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10, 10, 3], name='input')`